# Intelligent up-to-date-check for a gradle task unzipping a file

Tags: gradle, unzip, build-system

My goal is to create a gradle task which fulfills the following requirements:

- unzip a file into a directory
- run as infrequent as possible (good up-to-date-check)
- should detect if something has changed in the unzipped directory

The initial thought was to use a task like that:

```
p.task("unzip", type: Copy) {
  def zipFile = p.file('some-zip-file.zip')
  def outputDir = p.file("$p.buildDir/unpacked")

  from p.zipTree(zipFile)
  into outputDir
}
```

If I create a file "test.txt" within $p.buildDir/unpacked and I rerun the unzip task, the file "test.txt" remains within the unpacked directory. The unzip task effectively performs obviously something similar to a "merge". Unfortunately that is not optimal since the content of /unpacked should be defined as the unzipped zip file.

The following solution unfortunately doesn't detect that the output directory "unpacked" has changed since the last execution of the task:

```
p.task("deleteUnzippedDirectory", type: Delete) {
  delete "$p.buildDir/unpacked"

  inputs.file p.file('some-zip-file.zip')
  outputs.dir p.file("$p.buildDir/unpacked")
}

p.task("unzip", type: Copy) {
  def zipFile = p.file('some-zip-file.zip')
  def outputDir = p.file("$p.buildDir/unpacked")

  from p.zipTree(zipFile)
  into outputDir

  dependsOn p.deleteUnzippedDirectory
}
```

Is there a way to achieve the desired result besides running "deleteUnzippedDirectory" every time? (outputs.upToDateWhen {false})